# Отфильтровать товары вукомерс по времени?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Собираю сайт проката инструмента, взял обычный плагин аренды времени для вукомерс, но получил проблемку  - необходимо выбрать из списка товаров уже арендованные, но в плагинах такой функции нет(и в аналогах тоже).
Есть ли  несложный способ организации фильтра ... в програмировании я неочь ((
Может у кого есть опыт которым могли бы поделиться ..

Comment: Тебе нужен плагин для бронирования/аренды. Они есть как отдельные, так и надстройки над WC.

Comment: такие плагины нехочу, нужно именно для товаров вукомерс, надстройки есть но они все без общей выборки/фильтрации по всем товарам... покрайней мере я ненашел такого в репозитории вордпресс

Comment: А ты серьёзно думаешь, что эта задача на пару строк кода, раз спрашиваешь на SO? Ищи устраивающие тебя плагины или заказывай на заказ, если что-то не подходит.

Comment: Ну, за спрос не бьют в нос .. ))) или бьют ))) Решил спросить... 250долларов, это то что сам вукрмерс предлагает,  для моего бизнеса пока многовато... "смайлик с разведенными руками". Мнеже нужно только по времени отфильтровать, другие фишки мне ненужны

Comment: а вообще я подумал что это можно реализовать через гугл календарь, только непойму пока с какой стороны подступится

Comment: Зачем же сразу 250.. Для начала надо в оф репо смотреть. Приблизительно так https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/rent+woocommerce/, https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/booking+woocommerce/ и тп